# Do higher mayhem levels give better loot, or only more of it?

Tags: borderlands-3

What are the benefits of playing in Mayhem 4 over Mayhem 1 as far as loot quality is concerned? I'm certain that the higher tiers drop "rare" loot more often, but is *quality* of the drops affected?

Let's say you're maximum level, and the stars and planets all align, and you get the exact same legendary drop from a boss you've killed on Mayhem 1 and on Mayhem 4. Will the Mayhem 4 legendary gun have a higher item level (better stats)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This post will be inaccurate when Mayhem 2.0 comes out**
[JorRaptor states (3:46)](https://youtu.be/aNdgVSbNJZI?t=221) that when the Mayhem 2.0 rework comes out, higher Mayhem levels will drop better versions of the same gear.

The legendary gun found on Mayhem 4 will NOT have better stats than Mayhem 1. The stat ranges are determined by the item level, which is more or less based on your character level.

However, you'll find much more loot on M4 which greatly increases your chance of finding a better roll for the item.

Additionally, M4 increases the chances of finding anointment on guns. Anointments are extremely powerful endgame, and for a M4 endgame farmer a non anointed item is essentially worthless. In this way, farming on M4 does make the dropped items better (but again, it's just **more likely** to be better).

Lastly, there are some items that only drop in Mayhem 4. Especially the Class Mods, these are generally very good an are unavailable at Mayhem 3 or lower.

Comment: Interesting, I think the video link definitely answers the question. Item levels do not currently scale based on difficulty, but they are planned to scale that way in the future. Specifically, when "Mayhem 2.0" comes out (planned April 2020).